# How can i use variable inside Vanilla JavaScript class to make a function based on boolean

Tags: javascript, class, boolean

I have a JS Class which is making a function of giving a border to an element when i click to another element. That means when I click on `.trigger` class element, it will give a border to `.content` class element. But this function only should be happen based on a Boolean condition.

If Boolean is Yes it should be give border, otherwise it should not work. My code works when I set the method inside the constructor parentheses with `this` keyword and I can also declare variable there. But I need the method outside the constructor based on my other code.

So how can I possible declare variable outside the constructor and inside the class. I need this using Class approach based on my project.

My code is as follows.

```js
class ParentSelector {
  constructor(trigger, content, condition) {
    this.trigger = document.querySelector(trigger);
    this.content = document.querySelector(content);
  }

  let outline = condition;

  makeOutline() {
    this.trigger.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
      if (condition) {
        e.target.nextElementSibling.style.border = "2px solid red";
      }
    })
  }
}

let a = new ParentSelector(".trigger", ".content", true);
a.makeOutline();
```

```html
<div class="one">
  <div class="trigger">Trigger</div>
  <div class="content">Content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: it's unclear why would you even want it "outside".

Comment: its based on a group project, so i need to follow the existing system of code. The existing system is declaring methods outside the constructor as following reference: https://javascript.info/class

Comment: Thank You mplungjan to modify the question well.

Comment: Arguments from the constructor aren't accessible during declaration. Class fields only makes sense for properties that aren't set in the constructor, so they have a default value. So, I still see no point of having it "outside" and you will still need to use `this` and be basically the same code.

Answer (score 1):

First, why some `onClick` whose only use case is the if-condition? Shouldn't you be like, inside `makeOutline()` :

```
makeOutline() {
    if (this.condition) {
      this.trigger.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        e.target.nextElementSibling.style.border = "2px solid red";
     })
    }
  }
```

?

Second, why are you trying to set local variables outside constructor/methods?

**UPDATE**: I see you're asking about declaring a class field outside of its constructor. In that case, you declare it at the top of the class. The following should work:

```
class ParentSelector {
  condition = false;

  constructor(trigger, content, condition) {
    this.trigger = document.querySelector(trigger);
    this.content = document.querySelector(content);
    this.condition = condition;
  }

  // ...
}
```

Feel free to ask me any questions you have about this!

Comment: He already said `this.condition` works. And if you need to ask for clarification, use comments.

Comment: I see now. 

I'll addendum this answer to, hopefully, answer that...

Comment: There is no point in keeping the old answer [and adding "UPDATE:"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255644/)

Comment: @MikeWarren Thanks for initiation, I need variable outside constructor based on the other code of project. That is the problem, i hope there is solution but its hard to figure out.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I saw nothing in that external link where they're creating a local non-field variable after a constructor and before a method.

Comment: Okay, but i wonder, why no solution for this simple doubt. I search in online too, but there is no any issues discussing about this. But its actually a basic requirement in my opinion.

Comment: @MikeWarren i able to find a solution. But your last comment was the thread helped me to figure out the idea. Thank You for giving me the hint of answer.

Answer (score 0):

at last i able to find the solution myself after a deep thinking. Following is the solution. Following is the code.

```js
class ParentSelector {
    constructor(trigger, content, condition) {
        this.trigger = document.querySelector(trigger);
        this.content = document.querySelector(content);
        this.outline = condition;
    }
    
        makeOutline(){
        this.trigger.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
            if (this.outline) {
                e.target.nextElementSibling.style.border = "2px solid red";
            }
        })
    }
}

let a = new ParentSelector(".trigger",".content", true);
a.makeOutline();
```

```html
<div class="one">
<div class="trigger">Trigger</div>
<div class="content">Content</div>
</div>
```